# getting arrays of values from dictionary by key

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, return-value

I have dictionary:

```
teamDictionary = {
1: {'name': 'Bob', 'team': 'A', 'status': 'Leave'},
2: {'name': 'George', 'team': 'C', 'status': 'Training'},
3: {'name': 'Sam', 'team': 'B', 'status': 'Travel'},
4: {'name': 'Phil', 'team': 'A', 'status': 'Leave'},
5: {'name': 'Georgia', 'team': 'C', 'status': 'Training'}
}
```

I need to get array of names:

```
['Bob','George','Sam','Phil','Georgia']
```

How shold I solve my problem?

Answer (score 2):

Using a list comprehension you can

1. Get the values in the dictionary.
2. For each of the values, get the `name`

```
TeamDictionary = {
1: {'name': 'Bob', 'team': 'A', 'status': 'Leave'},
2: {'name': 'George', 'team': 'C', 'status': 'Training'},
3: {'name': 'Sam', 'team': 'B', 'status': 'Travel'},
4: {'name': 'Phil', 'team': 'A', 'status': 'Leave'},
5: {'name': 'Georgia', 'team': 'C', 'status': 'Training'}
}
```

```
print([x['name'] for x in TeamDictionary.values()])
> ['Bob', 'George', 'Sam', 'Phil', 'Georgia']
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
names = [value['name'] for key, value in teamDictionary.items()]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easyly do this in one line using array comprehension.

```
names = [item['name'] for item in teamDictionary.values()]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can iterate through the dictionary keys and for each item you can 'take' the name property like:

```
names = [teamDictionary[key]['name'] for key in teamDictionary]
```